# Earliest sources for the hot-rock method of hagalah

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

What is the earliest source explaining how to do hagalah? What is the earliest place we see detailed instructions for the hot rock method as opposed to the clay/dough method?

To elaborate:

If you have a pot which is too big to fit into another pot, how do you do hagalah? Mishne Torah says, build up the rim with some clay or dough and boil water in it. But today people will fill it with boiling water, then throw a heated rock in. So I would like to find the earliest mention of doing it this second way

Answer (score 1):

I think the first mention of this is by the Rosh in the second perek of Pesachim, in the name of Rabbeinu Yoel and (his son) the Raavya. See the [top of the left column in the Rosh.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37955&st=&pgnum=265)

Answer (score 0):

### The source for Hagala with a pot that is too big is a Tosafos in Avoda Zara (עד:)

> דרש רבא נעוה ארתחו. פירוש הגעילו הגתיות הגדולים .. מכאן אומר ר''ת
>   דעירוי ככלי ראשון מדאמר הכא דעל ידי עירוי מפליט היין הבלוע בגת דעל
>   כרחך ע''י עירוי קאמר הכא שהרי הגת גדולה וכבידה שאין יכולין לתתה לתוך
>   יורה מרותחת כדי להגעילה אלא ע''כ על ידי עירוי קאמר והשתא כיון דהוה
>   ככלי ראשון אם כן הני כלים שנאסרו ע''י כלי ראשון סגי להו בהגעלה ע''י
>   עירוי

### Regardig the Hot Stone method:

See the Rema (Orach Chaim 451:6) who quotes this Lehalacha in the name of the Mordechai (פ' כ"ש) and the Hagahos Maimonis (פ"ה) and the Sefer H'agur and the Issur V'heter (כלל נח):

> ב) **הנה מקור הדין של אבן מלובן מצוין בהרמ״א שם להמרדכי והגה״מ ואמר
>   ואיסור והיתר**,  ואעתיק כאן דבריהם מה שנוגע לשאלתינו, המרדכי כתב(בפ־ כ ל
>   שעה) דיתן על הקערה האבן דערה  עליו המים רותחין. ובהגה״מ(סוף הל־ חמץ
>   ומצה ב הל' הגעלה) כתב הדפין הגדולים שאין יכולים להכנים  בכלי כתב בשם
>   הריב״א שילבנו אבנים וישימם על הדף וישפוך עליהם מים רותחין, וכן יעשה 
>   לחבית שהשימו בה שכר או קערה גדולה. ולא כתבו שם דיעביר האבן על כל הכלי.
>
> ובאגור (אות תשמ־־ב) כתב אם י״ל כלים גדולים שאינם נכנסים ביורה ירתיח
>   לבינה או אבן באש  עד שתהיה חם מאד. ויתן האבן על הכלי או בצבת ומחזיקו
>   למעלה מן הכלי ושופך עליו מים ממי  הרותחין שביורה, ויעביר האבן על הכלי
>   יעד שהמים יעברו על הכלי׳ וזה חשוב כמו הגעלה, וכן  נוהגים להכשיר בזה
>   האופן כל כלי עץ הגדולים והשלחנות ודומיהן. ומבואר מזה דהעיקר הוא  שהמים
>   יעברו על כל הכלי אבל לא כתב שהאבן צריך שיגע בכל הכלי, ובאיסור
>   והיתר(שער נ־־ח  א ות ע־) כתב בדין הגעלת ע״י אבנים הדף ושלחן בזה״ל,
>   יזהר לכחחלה לגלגל אבן המלובן לכמה  מקומות על השלחן, ובכל פעם ישפוך
>   הרותחים עליו עד שלא ישאר מקום על השלחן שלא עברו  המים בשעת רתיחתם.
>   מובא בדרכי מש ה (ירד ס י ק כ״א א ות ד), הרי דכתב בפירוש דהאבן יניח רק 
>   על כמה מקומות שבשלחן והעיקר הוא שיגיע המים מרותחים בכל מקום

Source for above quoted text from [this Kuntres](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_49833_116.pdf)